# How to segment/split words in file

Tags: go, split

I have a file with a lot of words in it, and i have to split the word that a part of it already existed or appear during the scanning of the file:

Some of the words in the file are

```
member
members
membership
memberships
```

I have tried this, but I wanted the first lines[i](which is a) to keep looping the next words

```
func Split(lines []string) string {
    for i := 0; i < len(lines)-1; i++ { // position of words
        j := i + 1
        fmt.Println(lines[i], lines[j])
        if strings.ContainsAny(lines[j], lines[i]) {
            s := strings.Split(dictionary[j], dictionary[i])
            fmt.Println(dictionary[i], ".", s)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

but it only outputs

```
member
member.s
members.hip
membership.s
```

The output that i want:

```
member
member.s
member.ship
members.hip
member.ships
members.hips
```

Comment: You question is unclear , what do you mean by looping the next word ?

Comment: @MostafaSolati i don't know how to explain it in words, but basically the code should check each letters in the word one by one, if the letters/some words in the word already appeared,the word would be split. And please do refer to the output for examples

Comment: @MostafaSolati extra output examples, member,member⋅ship, member⋅ships, members⋅hip

Comment: Why the last one turned to members.hip instead of member.ship ?

Comment: @MostafaSolati because members is also a word that appears before membership, i forgot to include it after member

Comment: Okay , lets assume there is a members , that should turn to member.s

Comment: @MostafaSolati yes, thats correct

Comment: @MostafaSolati member, member.s, member.ship, members.hip

Comment: You are wrong if members splits to members.s then membership cannot split to members.hip because members splitted earlier so it's not a new word to split new words based on that

Comment: @MostafaSolati it is not based from the next words, it is based from the entire words in the file, as long as the word already appear, if the next word contains the word, it will be split

Comment: What you want leads to something like this m.e.m.b.e.r.s.h.i.p.s because eventually we have smaller words that contain one or two letters

Comment: @MostafaSolati in the file there is no m, e,b,r,s,h,i,p by itself, so m.e.m.b.e.r.s.h.i.p is not possible

Comment: `I have a file with a lot of words in it,`  says what you have is a generic file but the example you have given clearly follows a pattern . Can you confirm if there are any special order in which words appear in the file or should it work on any random file ?

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai from a to z, another example i could give is begone, be.gone, beg.one

Comment: @strawberrylatte can you update the question with these examples.  The details are in comments , it would be good to update the question in a manner that the question does not imply assumptions

Comment: @strawberrylatte please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given input following would help.

```
func splitSegmant(prev string, cur string) string {
    if len(cur) < len(prev) || cur[:len(prev)] != prev {
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", cur[:len(prev)], cur[len(prev):])
}

func Split(lines []string) []string {
    splits := []string{lines[0]}
    for i := 0; i < len(lines); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < i; j++ {
            split := splitSegmant(lines[j], lines[i])
            if split != "" {
                splits = append(splits, split)
            }
        }
    }
    return splits
}
```

you may find working code here : [playground](https://play.golang.com/p/E-oDF5APo_t)

Comment: may i know what this means? cur[:len(prev)] , is the current word length output is similar to previous word length?

Comment: slice of current word upto the length of prev (here it could be any one of the previous words)